# Pandas : Create new column based on text values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```python
    id          text                    labels
0   447         glutamine synthetase    [protein]
1   447         GS                      [protein]
2   447         hepatoma                [indication]
3   447         NaN                      NaN
4   442         Metachromatic           [indication]
```

I want to transform the dataframe and create two new columns named `proteins` and `indications` that contain the `text` when `labels` is protein or indication **for the same id**.

**Wanted output**

```python
    id          protein                     indication
0   447         glutamine synthetase, GS    hepatoma
0   442         NaN                         Metachromatic
```

Can someone help how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.explode` with `Groupby.agg` and `df.pivot`:

```
In [417]: out = df.explode('labels').groupby(['id', 'labels'])['text'].agg(','.join).reset_index().pivot('id', 'labels').reset_index().droplevel(0, axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1)

In [423]: out.columns = ['id', 'indication', 'protein']

In [424]: out
Out[424]: 
    id     indication                  protein
0  442  Metachromatic                      NaN
1  447       hepatoma  glutamine synthetase,GS
```